# having Error returning this anonymous to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[1] i want to pass the anonymous list to the view but I'm finding it difficult
please help me with the code:

i have the Model as :

```
namespace OpenOrderFramework.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "ID")]
    public class Item
    {
        private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Catagorie:")]
        public int CatagorieId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Item name cannot be empty, this is required")]
        [DisplayName("Item Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("GRC TAG")]
        public string GRCTag { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Location:")]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Item Name:")]
        public int itemnameId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity of item in a Location is required!")]
        [DisplayName("Quantity in Store:")]
        public int ItemQty { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

controller is:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        // GET: Items
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {                      
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "Name";
            ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Name" ? "Loc_desc" : "Location";
            IEnumerable<Item> items = db.Items;
           var ko= (from r in items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Catagorie, x.ItemName })
                                  .Select(g => new 
                                  {
                                      Catagorie = g.Key.Catagorie.Name,
                                      ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                                      ItemQty = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                                      Location = g.First().Location.Name

                                  })
                         select r).ToList();


                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
                {
                    items = items.Where(s => s.ItemName.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                               || s.Catagorie.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                                               s.Location.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20);
                    //}

                }
                else
                {
                    items = items.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
                }

            return View(ko.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));

        }
```

and the View is :

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Catagory
        </th>
       <th>
            Item Name.
        </th>
 <th>
            Quantity.
        </th>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font color="RED">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Catagorie.Name)
                </font>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)
            </td>            
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemQty)
            </td>
```

[2] please help me with the code and return the filterd list to the view .
tried so many but not working.. got this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList'1[<>f__AnonymousType7`4[System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList'1[OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item]'

please help me with the code to return the anonymous list to my ipagedlist

Answer (score 0):

In your View change:

`@model PagedList.IPagedList<OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item>`

To

`@model PagedList.IPagedList<dynamic>`

Answer (score 0):

your view states in the very first line ...

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item>
```

the object you are supposed to hand over as a parameter to the View() call needs to have this type ...

having anonymous objects as model in a razor view is unsupported, you can treat them as dynamics but you loose compile time checking (you shouldn't do that)

instead of an anonymous object, create model or viewmodel objects for your view and hand them over, maybe you can reuse the item class for this

**EDIT:**

you want a code sample...

the problem starts here with your anon type ...

```
                                 .Select(g => new 
                                  {
                                      Catagorie = g.Key.Catagorie.Name,
                                      ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                                      ItemQty = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                                      Location = g.First().Location.Name

                                  })
```

create a new class with a name suitable for your current naming convention and application architecture:
the class will hold data that does not represent an entity in your db but a grouped aggregation result. if that data is only to be used in that one view, it qualifies as a view model ... when in doubt what layer in your application this class belongs to, see it as a data transfer object or DTO

in this example i will call it ItemSumDTO, it has the same properties as your anon type

instead of creating anon type objects in the select above, create ItemSumDTOs

```
.Select(g => new
```

becomes

```
.Select(g => new ItemSumDTO
```

if your ORM has a problem with that replacement, stick to the anon object at this time, and later, after the call to .ToList() introduce another `.Select(x=> new ItemSumDTO{Catagorie = x.Catagorie, ItemName = x.ItemName, ItemQty = x.ItemQty, Location = x.Location})`

in your View, change the `@model` definition to be a `PagedList.IPagedList<ItemSumDTO>`

Comment: i changed the view to dynamic and still gives error

Comment: since you should not do that anyways, i think using a normal model or viewmodel class should do the trick...